# I am posting some values and getting response as array in retrofit but am getting error

Tags: android, mysql, json, retrofit

Error saying:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $ in retrofit

This is my function:

```
public interface I_GetStockTransferForLocation {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/DataAccessService.svc/GetStockTransferForLocation")
    void getStockFrLocation(@Field("COMPANY_ID")
    String companyId ,@Field("LOCATION_ID")
    String locationId ,@Field("TRANSACTION_DATE")
    String transactionDate ,
        Callback<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn> callback); } 

public class RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn { 
    @SerializedName("StockTransferList") private List<StockTransferList> 
    stockTransferList = new ArrayList<StockTransferList>(); 
    @SerializedName("Transfer_Date")
    private String transferDate; }

private void getStockTransferFrLocation() {

    RestAdapter adapterGetStockTransfer = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
            .build(); //Finally building the adapter

    //Creating object for our interface
    I_GetStockTransferForLocation api = adapterGetStockTransfer.create(I_GetStockTransferForLocation.class);

    api.getStockFrLocation(strCompanyId, strLocationId, strST_date, new Callback<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn>() {
        @Override
        public void success(RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn, retrofit.client.Response response) {

            List<StockTransferList> stockTransferLists = rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn.getStockTransferList();

            db = new Database(context);
            stckTransferFk = db.getLastStock();

            if (stckTransferFk == 0){

                stckTransferFk = 1;
            }
            else{
                stckTransferFk =  stckTransferFk + 1;
            }

            if(stockTransferLists.size()>0) {

                db = new Database(context);
                db.clearStockTransferData();
                db.createStockTransfer(rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn.getTransferDate(), stockTransferLists,stckTransferFk);

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.dj.prachi");
                intent.putExtra("customers_count",db.getCustomerCount()+"");
                intent.putExtra("products_count",db.getProductCount()+"");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

                Log.e("Prachi","Stock Transfer array"+stockTransferLists.size());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Log.e("Prachi","Stock Transfr Error"+error.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

and my response is

```
[
  {
    "StockTransferList": [
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12107",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12108",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "30.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12109",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "30.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12110",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12111",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "30.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12112",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "30.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12113",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12114",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12115",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12116",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12117",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12118",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12119",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      },
      {
        "CLOSING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "COMPANY_ID": "7",
        "LOCATION_ID": "1",
        "OPENING_STOCK_QTY": "0.00",
        "STOCKITEM_ID": "12120",
        "TRANSACION_ID": "0",
        "TRANSFER_IN_QTY": "0.00"
      }
    ],
    "Transfer_Date": "25/06/2016"
  }
]
```

Comment: show the `RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn` class code. And I would suggest you to better name your classes and variables :)

Comment: This error is shown when you are trying to get jsonobject when it is not object but is array or when you are trying to get array when its is object and not array. Please give your dataobject class so that we can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: can nebdy help me out please

Comment: I've edited my ans please try the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to how you've setup the call `I_GetStockTransferForLocation`, which from the code seems to expect a single object - `RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn`, but indeed from the json you've posted it looks like you should get a list of these objects.

You just need to change the definition of `I_GetStockTransferForLocation` to use `List<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn>` instead of just `RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn` and you should be fine.

You'll also need to adjust the callbacks from `void success(RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn, retrofit.client.Response response)` to `void success(List<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn> rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn, retrofit.client.Response response)`.

If you look at the error you're getting - **Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY** - It's `gson` way of saying that he was expecting a json with an object, but it's actually getting a list of objects. In your case this is how the interface would work:

```
public interface I_GetStockTransferForLocation { 
   @FormUrlEncoded          
   @POST("/DataAccessService.svc/GetStockTransferForLocation") 
   void getStockFrLocation(@Field("COMPANY_ID") String companyId,
                           @Field("LOCATION_ID") String locationId,
                           @Field("TRANSACTION_DATE") String transactionDate,
                           Callback<List<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn>> callback); }
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Create parent pojo as below and get response in that pojo:

```
public class ParentPojo extends List<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn > {
}
```

And your method will look like below:

```
private void getStockTransferFrLocation() {

RestAdapter adapterGetStockTransfer = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL) //Setting the Root URL
        .build(); //Finally building the adapter

//Creating object for our interface
I_GetStockTransferForLocation api = adapterGetStockTransfer.create(I_GetStockTransferForLocation.class);

api.getStockFrLocation(strCompanyId, strLocationId, strST_date, new Callback<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn>() {
    @Override
    public void success(ParentPojo rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn, retrofit.client.Response response) {

        for(int i=0;i<rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn.length;i++){
        List<RFResp_GetStockTransferFrLocatn > stockTransferLists= rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn.get(i).getStockTransferList();

        db = new Database(context);
        stckTransferFk = db.getLastStock();

        if (stckTransferFk == 0){

            stckTransferFk = 1;
        }
        else{
            stckTransferFk =  stckTransferFk + 1;
        }

        if(stockTransferLists.size()>0) {

            db = new Database(context);
            db.clearStockTransferData();
            db.createStockTransfer(rfResp_getStockTransferFrLocatn.getTransferDate(), stockTransferLists,stckTransferFk);

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.dj.prachi");
            intent.putExtra("customers_count",db.getCustomerCount()+"");
            intent.putExtra("products_count",db.getProductCount()+"");
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

            Log.e("Prachi","Stock Transfer array"+stockTransferLists.size());
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        Log.e("Prachi","Stock Transfr Error"+error.getMessage());
    }
});
}
```